# Invalid Syntax when I use python-shell-send-buffer in Emacs Python-mode

Tags: python, windows, emacs

Recently, I'm trying to configure emacs as my python IDE and I use anaconda in my computor.
I have use conda package and python-mode in emacs in the init.el as following:

```
(use-package conda
  :ensure t
  :init
(setq conda-anaconda-home (expand-file-name "D:/Anaconda"))
(setq conda-env-home-directory (expand-file-name "D:/Anaconda/envs")))
(use-package python-mode
  :ensure t
  :hook (python-mode . lsp-deferred)
  :custom
  (dap-python-debugger 'debugpy)
  :config
  (require 'dap-python))
```

and in my anaconda env, I have five environments:

```
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  D:\Anaconda
PyCharm                  D:\Anaconda\envs\PyCharm
Pyflow                   D:\Anaconda\envs\Pyflow
gluon                    D:\Anaconda\envs\gluon
tensorflow               D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow
```

I can open a shell in emacs and activate the base environment and run python.
But in the emacs when I am trying to run a py file. When I use `M-x run-python` and it didn't run my python scripts. After that, I try to use `python-shell-send-buffer` to run the script but it threw out the following eroor:

```
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:/Users/Travis/AppData/Local/Temp/pyQTizRq", line 1
    Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And When I open this directory '''c:/Users/Travis/AppData/Local/Temp/'''this file doesn't exist.
My system is windows 10 and emacs 27.2.
How can I fix the problem and it can run the script directly?

Comment: `run-python` creates a new buffer where Python runs a REPL which you can talk to. It's not clear whether this is something you understand and expect, or if you hope it should do something it doesn't. If you are trying to run `python-shell-send-buffer` in that `*Python*` buffer then it will do exactly what I described in the previous comment. This looks like pilot error but we can't correct your expectations if you don't spell them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to use `python-shell-send-buffer` is to run it from a buffer of Python code; Emacs will then send the contents of that buffer to the Python REPL you started with `run-python`.

Don't run this command in the `run-python` buffer (`*Python*`) itself; it doesn't make any sense to submit that buffer's contents to Python as code.

To quickly demonstrate how this works,

- Create a buffer `demo.py` and type some Python code into it.

  ```py
  print("Hello Emacs")
  ```
- Split the frame into two panes (oddly called "windows" in Emacs terminology) `C-x 2`
- In one of the panes, execute `M-x run-python`
- Switch to the other pane (`C-x o`), and execute `M-x python-shell-send-buffer`
- Observe how the command gets entered at the Python REPL prompt in the `*Python*` buffer, and the results are visible there.

If the buffer with your Python code is running `python-mode`, there is a shortcut key `C-c C-c` to submit the buffer to the REPL, so you don't need to type the long and complex `M-x` command sequence.

The evaluation function works by creating a temporary file in the background, but that will be gone again by the time you try to inspect it.